# Can we modify existing sonarway ruleset?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Can we modify existing sonarway ruleset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Sonarqube 6.7.2 and i can't but you can copy an existing profile and modify it as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of SonarQube. [Since 6.5 quality profiles are read-only](https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-6.5-in-screenshots). In previous versions you can modify them, but it is not recommended.

The best option is to create your own Quality Profile. You can create it:

- from zero and add all necessary rules
- inherit from built-in profiles and modify it (add/remove/reconfigure rules).

You can mark created profiles as default, so every project will use it.

Read more about [Quality Profiles](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles).

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification